# How to create a "serialized" version of a model?

Tags: python, serialization, machine-learning, neural-network

I created a model with the following code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=14, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=16)
```

I am trying to create a serialized version of the best version of this model.

What I know is:

Serialization is the process of converting an object into a stream of bytes in order to store the object.

What I don't know is:

How do I convert the model I have created into the above defined stream of bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(model, open('./output.bin', 'w'))
```